# How do I plot a timeseries so it starts and ends at the middle of the year

Tags: matplotlib, time-series

My data is monthly data arranged in the order of the months of the year (so Jan first and Dec last), however, I would like the plot to begin with July and end with June, so Dec and Jan would effectively be at the center of the plot. Im using matplotlib to plot and my data is either from pandas series of just from a list.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: matplotlib will assign the first (earliest) date to the first tick and move on till the last date at the end (right-end). So, keep the earliest date at June and the last/largest date at May of next year. Please provide code and data you are working with if you are not able to get your code to work